# Issue with Custom Domain Standard Email Template image not render

Tags: workflow, email-template, custom-domain

I am facing a problem with an email template which is bind with a workflow. The issue occurs only when we use custom domain. When the email template is fired through workflow from custom domain , The image didn't get displayed.

However things go find when workflow and email template works internally.

When I replace the standard with custom email template things go well with both salesforce internal Org as well as community.

Please assist